# Is it possible to share system frameworks from embedded Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, libraries

I have an Xcode project that i always embed into my app projects like so :

[image: Embedded Project]

My question : Is it possible to share the system frameworks from my embedded project so that i don't have to go into 'Link Binary with Libraries' in my top level project and add the frameworks a second time?  I am always forced to always do this because i get a ton of dependency errors when I try to compile without adding the frameworks.

Comment: The limitation of embedding frameworks is that you cannot share the framework among a suite of applications. If your company develops a suite of applications that rely on the same framework, you might want to install one copy of that framework that all of the applications can share. In such a situation, you should install the frameworks in the /Library/Frameworks directory and make sure the frameworks bundle does not contain any public header information

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you consider a "system framework", I would recommend to think about using a dependency management tool:

http://cocoapods.org

At first this might look as if this does not fit with your question, but it basically does the following: you create a project with Xcode, then make it so called "pod". Later you can simply reference this "pod" in any other project you want. There is one significant advantage over using the Apple recommended way of installing frameworks in "/Library/Frameworks": you can update/replace/delete/move them as you like and it does not interfere with other projects on your machine.